# How to tar up HHVM git branch for use with rpmbuild

Tags: git, hhvm

I have created an rpm spec for hhvm but when it executes I receive the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:29 (MESSAGE):
  third-party/CMakeLists.txt missing.  Try updating your submodule with:

  rm -r third-party

  git submodule update --init --recursive
```

which I have done and then created the tarball again with:

```
git archive --format=tar.gz --prefix=hhvm-3.7.0/ origin/master > ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/hhvm-3.7.0.tar.gz
```

but still I get the same error.  What am I doing wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We actually provide full source tarballs ourselves, which you can just download: http://dl.hhvm.com/source/

Those are generated by this script: https://github.com/hhvm/packaging/blob/master/hhvm/sources/package

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using https://github.com/Kentzo/git-archive-all and then creating the tarball by:

```
git-archive-all --prefix=hhvm-3.7.0 hhvm-3.7.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: This can also work, but please don't distribute anything as 3.7.0 -- that version doesn't exist yet. We'll tag it on github when we make a release.